# Is it possible to have different passwords for each endpoint in StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, distributed-caching

I am trying to setup endpoints for master and slave. As per the Basics documentation https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html you can connect to multiple Redis servers, and StackExchange.Redis will automatically determine the master/slave setup.

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("server1:6379,server2:6379");
```

Is it possible to have different passwords for master and slave setup?

Here is my code for Master setup, i can add more endpoints to setup slave but not sure if Redis allows different passwords for Master and Slave.

```
  var configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
  {
   EndPoints = { { cachedserver.Host, cachedserver.Port }, },
   Password = cachedserver.Password,
   SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `redis` connection string format is like this:

```bash
arbitrary_usrname:password@ipaddress:6379
```

So by having multiple connection strings separated by comma (`,`) you can achieve it:

ConnectionStrings:

```bash
arbitrary_usrname1:password@ipaddress1:6379,arbitrary_usrname2:password@ipaddress2:6379
```

Code:

```cs
var configurationOptions = ConfigurationOptions.Parse("connectionStrings");

ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions);//also you can pass connectionStrings directly
```

Comment: How would you configure this with configuration options ?

Comment: The result of ``ConfigurationOptions.Parse`` is configuration options, if you want to set extra settings you edit it after parsing. See the code here: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConfigurationOptions.cs#L656

Comment: Do you have any online reference to multiple connection strings as i think only one password is allowed in master / slave setup.